# ZFS on Linux: Setting up NFS on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, macosx, nfs, zfs

I upgraded my headless server from 13.10 to 14.04, but borked the upgrade (and stupidly didn't have a backup image - lesson learnt). Hence, I'm reinstalling everything from scratch. I have a working zpool set up with several datasets, and am trying to get NFS set up to access it across my network from my Macbook. Previously, I had it working by specifying shares in /etc/exports, but I no longer have a copy of that file and cannot remember the options I specified.

I've tried following the process in http://bit.ly/1hgArRk, but `# showmount -e` results in no mounts shown. `zfs get sharenfs` returns

```
NAME                  PROPERTY  VALUE                        SOURCE
data/music_lossless   sharenfs  rw=@192.168.0.0/24,insecure  local
```

When instead I specify in /etc/exports

```
/mnt/data/music_lossless        192.168.0.0/24(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

From `# showmount -e` I get `/mnt/data/music_lossless 192.168.0.0/24`, but cannot connect from my Macbook.

`$ rpcinfo -p 192.168.0.126` on the Macbook confirms nfs is visible:

```
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    2   tcp   2049
100227    3   tcp   2049
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    2   udp   2049
100227    3   udp   2049
```

Can anyone see immediately what's going wrong, or give me hints as to how I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

To restore the exports use `zfs share -a`.  This will happen at boot if you set `ZFS_SHARE="yes"` in `/etc/default/zfs`.

Your manual setup looks okay, but you did not make it clear if your `data/music_lossless` zfs is actually mounted on `/mnt/data/music_lossless`.

Comment: `data/music_lossless` is mounted on `/mnt/data/music_lossless`. I've looked into this whole picture a bit more, and it seems the problem may be at my OS X end. At least, that's what I deduce from the fact that my OpenElec media box connects to the NFS shares without issue. I'll update/post new answer if I get round to unravelling it. For now, I'm just using SMB...